# plots circular points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Below is an image demonstrating my question. In short, how do i figure out how to plot the yellow points?

- The outside circle has a radius of 8
- The inside circle has a radius of 6
- The red line indicates the start and end each circular arc
- The red line is offset 2 units on both axis

[image]

Below is a snippet of code I use to plot circular points, but im not sure how to adjust it to plot the desired affect.

[image]

```
fn build_ring__part_points radius:8 radius2:6 count:6 =
(
    local step = 90.0 / count
    for i = 0 to count do
    (
        local ang = i * step

        /* outside radius */
        local x = radius * cos(-ang)
        local y = radius * sin(-ang)
        outsidePt = [x, y, 0]

        /* inside radius */
        local x = radius2 * cos(-ang)
        local y = radius2 * sin(-ang)
        insidePt = [x, y, 0]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two points on the horizontal segment correspond to the following angles:

\begin{array}{cc}
   \sin \theta_{00} = \dfrac 26 & \sin \theta_{10} = \dfrac 28 \\
   \theta_{00} = \arcsin \dfrac 13 & \theta_{10} = \arcsin \dfrac 14
\end{array}

The two points on the vertical segment correspond to the following angles:

\begin{array}{cc}
   \cos \theta_{06} = \dfrac 26 & \cos \theta_{16} = \dfrac 28 \\
   \theta_{06} = \arccos \dfrac 13 & \theta_{16} = \arccos \dfrac 14
\end{array}

So $\theta_{0k} = \theta_{00} + \dfrac k6(\theta_{06}-\theta_{00})$

and $\theta_{1k} = \theta_{10} + \dfrac k6(\theta_{16}-\theta_{10})$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to solve $x^2 + y^2 = 8$ with fixed $x$ values. The solution to this is $y = \sqrt{8 - x^2}$. So for whatever $x$ you are currently on, you can simply use that as your value for $y$.

For example, when $x = 2$, you get $y = \sqrt{8 - 2^2} = \sqrt{4} = 2$.